# Exception while executing stored procedure odp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, odp.net

I've executed around 5 stored procedures with the below code (parameters will vary with respect to Stored procedure). Those are working fine except the below SP.
output of the below code is:
p_out=2
p_msg= 'exception while execution'

In SP, it going to exception block. Can anybody let me know the exact issue.

Code:

```
  Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("OracleDBConnectionString");       
   OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand();       
   oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;       
   oracleCommand.CommandText = "PCK_ADMIN.PROC_VALIDATE_USER";       
   oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("P_USERNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "ddd";         
   oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("P_out", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction =   ParameterDirection.Output;      
   oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("P_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

db.ExecuteNonQuery(oracleCommand);
string outValue = oracleCommand.Parameters["P_out"].Value.ToString();
string outMsg = oracleCommand.Parameters["P_msg"].Value.ToString();
```

Stored Procedure is:

```
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY PCK_ADMIN AS

PROCEDURE PROC_VALIDATE_USER
                          (P_USERNAME IN USR_USER.USERNAME%TYPE,
                           P_out  OUT NUMBER,
                           P_msg  OUT VARCHAR2) AS

 v_cnt      NUMBER(5):=0;

BEGIN

P_OUT := 0;

Select count(USERID) into v_cnt from usr_user
where username = P_USERNAME;

IF v_cnt = 0 then
  p_out := 0;
  p_msg := 'Record doesnot exists';
ELSE
  p_out := 1;
  p_msg := 'Record already exists';
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
 p_out := 2;
 p_msg := 'exception while execution';
 END PROC_VALIDATE_USER;
 END PCK_ADMIN;
```

Table Structure of usr_user is

```
 USERNAME   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
 USERID     NUMBER
```

Comment: Before executing the SP from `C#` code. Have you tried to execute the SP from SQL? - Try this in SQL : `exec (your stored proc name) (and possibly add parameters)`. Any exception there as well?

Comment: Yes, its working and it returned expected results from SQL editor

Comment: I'm suspecting the Parameters. Okay lets try this - Remove the parameters from SP. Declare local variables in it and Hard Code the Data for Testing Purpose. From C# code you just call the SP. Check it whether its working or not. If works add parameters one by one and call from Code. This is just to make sure passing parameters are not causing the Issue.

Comment: I tried this. Still it is going to exception block

Comment: Have you checked the `Inner Exception` while exception throw in Code. (Some kind of exceptions will have the more details in it) Not sure what's going on. :(

Comment: After 4 hours of time spending, I come up with a solution. I specified size for P_msg output parameter and it worked. Thank you RJK, for your comments. oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("P_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

Comment: No problem. Just provide the solution as an answer and accept it yourself. It will help some one in the future.

Comment: If you want information on exceptions, in the future please provide the entire exception in your question, including the ORA error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I specified size for P_msg output parameter and it worked.

```
oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("P_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```